# Why Val loss is not showing ? how to display it then plot it with training loss

Tags: machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, dataset, training-data, large-language-model

after fine tune the pytorch llm(IDEFICS9b) on the data set the train results is not showing val loss how to collect it and then plot it with training loss?

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=f"{model_name}-vqa1",
    learning_rate=3e-5,
    fp16=True,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,
    dataloader_pin_memory=False,
    save_total_limit=3,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    save_strategy="steps",
    save_steps=10,
    eval_steps=10,
    logging_steps=10,
    max_steps=1000,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
    push_to_hub=False,
    label_names=["labels"],
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    report_to=None,
    optim="paged_adamw_8bit",
)
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_ds,
    eval_dataset=eval_ds,
)

train_results = trainer.train()
```

the train results is as follows:

> TrainOutput(global_step=10, training_loss=2.2117252349853516, metrics={'train_runtime': 15.7995, 'train_samples_per_second': 10.127, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.633, 'total_flos': 470670709819392.0, 'train_loss': 2.2117252349853516, 'epoch': 0.02})